# JSF welcome file is not recognized

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

Accessing

```
http://localhost:8080/basicSetup/faces/index.xhtml
```

works, with the output of :

> Hello World ! Albert Kam

but accessing

```
http://localhost:8080/basicSetup
```

shows

> Hello World ! #{myBean.value}

meaning that the welcome file is not rendered as a JSF file

I would like `http://localhost:8080/basicSetup` to have the same effect as accessing `http://localhost:8080/basicSetup/faces/index.xhtml`.

Please share your thoughts

jetty-maven-plugin:8.0.3.v20111011:run + jdk 7 + eclipse indigo

Here is my web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Basic Setup Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

and this is the jetty maven plugin output :

```
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:8.0.3.v20111011:run (default-cli) @ BasicSetup >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ BasicSetup ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ BasicSetup ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ BasicSetup ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\albert\workspace\BasicSetup\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ BasicSetup ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:8.0.3.v20111011:run (default-cli) @ BasicSetup <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:8.0.3.v20111011:run (default-cli) @ BasicSetup ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: BasicSetup Maven Webapp
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory C:\Users\albert\workspace\BasicSetup\src\main\webapp does not exist. Defaulting to C:\Users\albert\workspace\BasicSetup\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = C:\Users\albert\workspace\BasicSetup\target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /basicSetup
[INFO] Tmp directory = C:\Users\albert\workspace\BasicSetup\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\Users\albert\workspace\BasicSetup\src\main\webapp
2011-10-25 14:03:59.073:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.0.3.v20111011
2011-10-25 14:03:59.333:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2011-10-25 14:04:00.104:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/basicSetup,[file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/, jar:file:/C:/Users/albert/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.3/javax.faces-2.1.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/]},file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/
2011-10-25 14:04:00.104:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/basicSetup,[file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/, jar:file:/C:/Users/albert/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.3/javax.faces-2.1.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/]},file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/
2011-10-25 14:04:00.104:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/basicSetup,[file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/, jar:file:/C:/Users/albert/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.3/javax.faces-2.1.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/]},file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/
Oct 25, 2011 2:04:00 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.3 (SNAPSHOT 20110908) for context '/basicSetup'
Oct 25, 2011 2:04:00 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Oct 25, 2011 2:04:00 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
2011-10-25 14:04:00.787:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/basicSetup,[file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/, jar:file:/C:/Users/albert/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.3/javax.faces-2.1.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/]},file:/C:/Users/albert/workspace/BasicSetup/src/main/webapp/
2011-10-25 14:04:00.825:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 STARTING
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 10 seconds.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `<welcome-file>` is supposed represent the **file** name of the file which is default to be loaded whenever a folder is been requested.

```
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

If you're using JSF 2.x, then I suggest to replace `/faces/*` URL pattern by `*.xhtml`, then the above will work and you do not need to fiddle with `/faces` paths in URLs anymore. Or, if you're using JSF 1.x, then I suggest to replace the `/faces/*` URL pattern by `*.jsf` and provide an empty `index.jsf` file next to `index.xhtml` in the folder to fool the container that the file really exist.

Comment: I completely agree with your idea for the simplicity sake of using just xhtml for my JSF2.x. I was just being curious about the problem in my case, since the examples of using folder path in the welcome-file is in http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-intro.html and in the core jsf 2 book..

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it works on Tomcat and Glassfish that way. I've actually never used `/faces/*` and I've always been in the impression that the `<welcome-file>` should refer a physical file on the disk, that is also literally what the spec says. Perhaps those containers autodetects matches with prefix-mapped servlets on the welcome file? I've myself also never used Jetty, but from what I've read is that it's at times pretty buggy and insane.

Comment: Thanks ! Will switch to *.xhtml for the sake of more common approach, and will think of switching to tomcat7 again